# How do I copy a query in Power Query to another workbook

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a query that I made in one of my workbook and now I need to repeat it in many other workbook as well.

How can I copy it to my other workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Within the `Data` ribbon, select `Queries & Connections`, then `right click` on the query you want to copy.

Select `COPY`, then open your other workbook and `PASTE` into the same `Queries and Connections` pane.

Comment: It's ok if a query doesn't have dependencies. Otherwise all of them will be copied. If you want to copy only one query, open Editor, copy content and paste it to target file as new query

Comment: This does not copy calculated columns. Is there a way to copy calculated columns as well and any other relationship the table may have ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are many workbooks and you regularly have to update or create query's that are in a 'master' Excel workbook, you also can automate it by using VBA - this is the solution I created.